# How to restore one contact from Address Book with Time Machine

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, time-machine

I want to restore one contact from my Address Book with Time Machine. To do so, I select the contact in Address Book. Then, I press the Time Machine icon in the dock. Then my address book is "taken into space".

However, when I browse back in time (either pressing the arrow back, or selecting a time on the right), the contact details do not change. And I am sure the data has been changed between dates. Also, when I **do** press restore, it's still the new data, not the backup.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using OS X 10.6.3 in combination with a external USB drive on an iMac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same version of OS X, same behavior.

I ran a backup, amended a contact, and went into time machine and it would not restore the old information.

I also deleted a contact and was unable to restore it, contrary to what [Apple support say here](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/11422.html) (at the foot of the page).

So I'd say it was a defect. Hopefully Address Book gets some TLC in the next version bump - Snow Leopard also messed up label printing.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Contacts is the active app. on your screen NOW before opening time machine thats the most important thing before starting....

Open Time Machine.
Time Machine displays the current state of Contacts in the foreground, with available backups in the background.

Use the arrows or the timeline along the right side of the screen to browse through the available backups.PICK A DATE PREVIOUS TO TODAY

Select one (or more groups or) card to restore, and then click Restore.
You can also recover contact information by importing an archive file of your contacts.